# Full featured alternative to Bind9?

Tags: untagged

I'm running Bind9 with 3 zones and 20 domain names (summary). Every day named process either crashes or just stops. Plus I really don't like its resouce consumption (more than 20M of RAM). Any ideas what can I use? I've already checked PowerDNS (which sux, because I want sane config files, not some database where I'll need to write SQL or half working BindBackend), NSD / Unbound (limited support of authoritative functionality), MaraDNS (same problem as NSD / Unbound + according to wiki page security issues and DDoS issues).

**UPD:** I'll try to be more specific: I need authoritative server + slpit-horizon + wildcards and configuration in plain text files. Thats it.

Comment: Bind is one of the most used DNS servers in the world... I find it quite strange it keeps crashing on you. You should probably try finding the root cause of this problem instead of just replacing it.

Comment: How did you install bind9? If you installed it using the package manager of your distribution (apt-get, yum, etc..), try to re-install it from source. [I am assuming you are running your bind on Linux]. Changing the way you installed the software can sometimes help. Also, I got a better performance when installed bind9 from source. There was a noticeable performance gain.

Comment: If you are so consistently crashing something as rock solid as BIND 9 why do you think some alternative is going to be any more stable? You need to fix your problems instead of trying to hide them.

Comment: I can't see how searching a replacement for BIND, learning about it strengths and weaknesses, the configuration syntax, the small and big differences compared to BIND etc.etc. can be considered the *easy way*.

Comment: If Bind is crashing, chances are something else is wrong with your system. Having said that, I don't think there are any DNS servers aside from BIND that are as fully featured, for any OS. There are many other DNS servers, but they're usually special-use servers. One may fit your needs, if you describe _which_ features you really need. But there is no "full featured bind replacement."

Comment: A whole 20MB of RAM?  Oh noes.  As Flimzy implied, "full featured" is not an RFP-quality description; if you want a good answer, you'll need to describe your requirements in a more concrete fashion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from what's been (correctly) said in the comments to your question about the questionable nature of this undertaking, [Wikipedia's "Comparison of DNS Server software"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software) page is a good starting point for feature comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with BIND9 but make sure you are NOT using it on a "cutting edge" distro.  For a stable server, stick with Debian Stable, Ubuntu LTS, or Red Hat/CentOS and install BIND9 from the distro's package manager.